# Link directly to Google Maps transit directions mobile site

Tags: iphone, google-maps, uiwebview

If you visit maps.google.com on a mobile device, then press 'Menu', 'Get Directions', and select the 'transit' option, you are taken to a page where you can enter two locations and a date/time, and get directions on public transit. However, the URL is still maps.google.com.

Is there any way to link directly to this page so that I can load it in a UIWebView in my iOS app? Would 'clicking' the buttons in Javascript be (the only/a good) solution?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you just delete the previous question and repost?

Comment: It had about 5 views in almost 24 hours. I didn't know why it had gotten so buried... sorry.

Comment: Not a big deal, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't hallucinating. Editing your question, maybe improving the question, will bump it, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even clicking the buttons in javascript doesn't seem to be working. The Google Maps code is a little strange- the event listeners aren't assigned directly and I can't get a .click() to work. So what I'll do is have the user enter the two locations in boxes in the app, then load something like http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=Coover+Hall&daddr=lied+rec+center in the UIWebView, except I'll add some more specific location information before building the URL, since this is a city-specific app. Not a perfect solution but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Try: http://www.google.com/transit

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but the mobile version of the site (redirects to google.com/m/directions) doesn't work quite the same as going through maps. There is no autosuggest as you type, and when not typing a complete address, it can't figure it out as well as maps.google.com. For example, visit google.com/m/directions and get directions from 'coover hall ames' to 'lied rec center ames'. It suggests the address for Coover but not Lied. Try the same in maps, and it works. But thanks for the link, that will probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a URL that links to the transit directions with the "dirflg=r" paramater.

Find the other URL parameters here: http://web.archive.org/web/20110714031648/http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters

Comment: Can you give an example link? I tried http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=111%20Davisville%20Avenue,Toronto,ON&destination=469%20King%20Street%20West,%20Toronto,%20ON&sensor=false&dirflg=r but it's still giving driving directions.